# Codeception: test data in annotation - codeception reports undefined variable

Tags: automated-testing, test-strategy, test-data, json, codeception

I've tried to use this style: https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Example-Annotation

My example test case is this:

```
/**
 * @example { "groupid": "16789507", "partnerccdid": "31003704" }
*/
public function getPartnerCcdIdWithGroupId(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->see($example["groupid"]);
}
```

When I run this using this command: `php codecept.phar run -vvv` I only get the following error:

```
[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined variable: example
```

According to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, it's a valid `JSON`.
I'm using it the way they explain in the official documentation, all my strings are enclosed in double quotes.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** I'm actually trying to use `SOAP module` and test an API. Just a thought crossed my mind.

Is this annotation style allowed with the module and `API Tester`? Because I can't figure out what else could possibly be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass in the $example as described in the documentation:

```
public function getPartnerCcdIdWithGroupId(ApiTester $I, \Codeception\Example $example)
```

Comment: :D of course. Well, I just didn't see that. Thank you.